# startswith in javascript error

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using `startswith` reg exp in Javascript

```
if ((words).match("^" + string))
```

but if I enter the characters like `, ] [ \ /`, Javascript throws an exception.
Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're matching using a regular expression you must make sure you pass a valid [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to match(). Check the [list of special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) to make sure you don't pass an invalid regular expression. The following characters should always be escaped (place a \ before it): [\^$.|?*+()

A better solution would be to use substr() like this:

```
if( str === words.substr( 0, str.length ) ) {
   // match
}
```

or a solution using indexOf is a (which looks a bit cleaner):

```
if( 0 === words.indexOf( str ) ) {
   // match
}
```

next you can add a startsWith() method to the string prototype that includes any of the above two solutions to make usage more readable:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(str) {
    return ( str === this.substr( 0, str.length ) );
}
```

When added to the prototype you can use it like this:

```
words.startsWith( "word" );
```

Comment: Don’t use `indexOf`. It searches the whole string and not just the start.

Comment: @Huppie: `indexOf(prefix) === 0` should work and doesn't require extracting a substring.

Comment: @Grant: Well, I edited the post to use substr() instead of contains() because of the remark of Gumbo. If you're adding a method to the string prototype anyway, you might as well want the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

One could also use indexOf to determine if the string begins with a fixed value:

```
str.indexOf(prefix) === 0
```

Comment: +1. `indexOf() === 0` makes more sense to me than taking a substring.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a string starts with a fixed value, you could also use `substr`:

```
words.substr(0, string.length) === string
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use regex you have to escape special characters in your string. PHP has a function for it but I don't know any for JavaScript. Try using following function that I found from [Snipplr][1]

```
function escapeRegEx(str)
{
   var specials = new RegExp("[.*+?|()\\[\\]{}\\\\]", "g"); // .*+?|()[]{}\
   return str.replace(specials, "\\$&");
}
```

and use as

```
var mystring="Some text";
mystring=escapeRegEx(mystring);
```

If you only need to find strings starting with another string try following

```
String.prototype.startsWith=function(string) {
   return this.indexOf(string) === 0;
}
```

and use as

```
var mystring="Some text";
alert(mystring.startsWith("Some"));
```